# Android - Create Application level fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle

For my current project, I will be using this [SlidingUpPanel library](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel).

The sliding up panel will host a fragment that will contain application/global level information. This panel will be in every activity in my application. This will be very similar to the way Google Play music works.

My question is, what is the best way to persist the sliding up panel fragment throughout my application? I see myself going about this in two ways...

1. Storing the fragment inside the Application class and loading it at the start of every activity (somehow, not even sure if this is a possibility).
2. Storing the data that it will display in the Application class & loading a new instance of the fragment, passing in the persisted data.

Which one of these two ways would be the best? Is 1. even possible? Are there any coding landmines with these approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a fragment to persist throughout the application lifecycle would be pretty unorthodox, mainly because the fragment class should be able to follow it's normal lifecycle events (in this case, mainly onPause and onResume) instead of being stuck somewhere in the application class.

It is definitely common practice to store the data and load it each time you display the fragment. If you want to enable some sort of cacheing or singleton pattern to access the data, it should most likely be with another object that the fragment can access but is not a member within the fragment.

There is a [good video from google about leaking views](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkbHeFHn8JY) and it touches briefly on the pitfalls of doing some similar to what you're proposing in bullet #1.

Comment: Those are good points, thanks for the advice. The more I thought about it, storing some sort of "session" structure for the fragment seems to be the best approach.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences for most of the 'session' stuff you want if you need a very fast way to retrieve data in that fragment without a database. Again though, I'd strongly recommend that you don't cache the fragment itself and just load back the state every time that you need the fragment.

Comment: That's what I'm going to do, seems to be the only way to do it correctly. Thanks you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I think the structure of your app looks like it should be a single activity where that bar is in it, then the main content is a `Fragment` that you replace and use `addToBackStack` on in order to maintain the use of the back button. Otherwise, you are going to have a lot of repeated code with solution 2 (which means a lot of repeated work in the case of bugs etc., not very maintainable), or leak views using solution 1.

[More info on providing a proper back implementation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html)

Comment: That is how the main content of the application is structured as far as the navigation drawer. There are some activities though that branch off from within the main activity and its content. Thanks you for your reply. I may restructure and convert those activities into fragments though which will help!